# Элементы массива обновляются но не реактивны

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Читаю что массивы сами по себе реактивны.

Создал массив из ошибок заранее (на всякий случай) в методе `Oninput` буду переключаю элемент массива в true либо false, в зависимости от того прошло поле проверку или нет.

Массив обновляется, но кажется он не реактивен, так как computed свойство `progress` не срабатывает повторно. Как можно исправить?

И второй вопрос, как я могу запустить валидацию еще при загрузке страницы если метод `validateInput` срабатывает только при вводе и при потере фокуса. Понимаю что по идее надо запустить этот метод еще и при  загрузке но при условии  что input уже чем то заполнен, чтобы не пугать пользователя ошибками сразу

Имя можно вводить только английскими буквами

Телефон только цифры больше 6 знаков

Если все верно то поле подсвечивается зеленым, а элементы массива `success_array`, должны переключаться в `true` либо `false`

```js
Vue.component('app-input', {
  props: ['value', 'pattern', 'name'],
  template: `
            <div class="form-group" :class="getStatus">
            <label>{{ this.name }}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" :value="value" @input="validateInput" @blur="validateInput">
            </div>
        `,
  data: () => ({
    is_valid: null,
  }),

  computed: {
    getStatus() {

      return {
        'success': this.is_valid,
        'error': this.is_valid === false,
      };
    },
  },

  methods: {
    validateInput(e) {

      this.is_valid = this.pattern.test(e.target.value);

      this.$emit('input', {
        value: e.target.value,
        valid: this.is_valid,
      });
    },


  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '.sample',
  data: () => ({
    info: [{
        name: 'Name',
        value: '444444',
        pattern: /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/,
      },
      {
        name: 'Phone',
        value: '',
        pattern: /^[0-9]{7,14}$/,
      },
      {
        name: 'Email',
        value: '',
        pattern: /.+/,
      },
      {
        name: 'Some Field 1',
        value: '',
        pattern: /.+/,
      },
      {
        name: 'Some Field 2',
        value: '',
        pattern: /.+/,
      },
    ],
    success_array: [],
  }),

  computed: {

    progress() {

      let success_length = 0;

      this.success_array.forEach(el => {
        console.log(el);

        if (el) {
          success_length++
        }
      })

      return {
        width: success_length / this.info.length * 100 + '%',
      };
    },
  },

  methods: {
    onInput(index, data) {
      this.info[index].value = data.value;
      this.success_array[index] = data.valid;
    },
  },

  beforeMount() {

    this.info.forEach((el, i) => {
      this.success_array.push(false);
    });
  },

});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}

.success {
  color: #3c763d;
}

.progress {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sample">
    <form>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" :style="progress"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <app-input v-for="(form_item, index) in info" :key="index" :value="form_item.value" :pattern="form_item.pattern" :name="form_item.name" @input="onInput(index, $event)"></app-input>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
                Send Data
            </button>
    </form>
    <div>

      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
>    `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the
>    array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

"*Вью не может определить, что массив обновлен в следующих случаях:"*

*1. Когда вы непосредственно переопределяете элемент по индексу*

*2. Когда вы изменяете длину массива*

> To overcome caveat 1, both of the following will accomplish the same as `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`, but will also trigger state updates in the reactivity system:

*Чтобы обойти первое ограничение и включить реактивность, используйте один из следующих вариантов*

> ```
> Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
> ```
>
> ```
> vm.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
> ```

То есть вместо

```js
onInput(index, data) {
  this.info[index].value = data.value;
  this.success_array[index] = data.valid;
}
```

используйте

```js
onInput(index, data) {
  this.info.splice(index, 1, data.value);
  this.success_array.splice(index, 1, data.valid);
}
```

---

> Понимаю что по идее надо запустить этот метод еще и при загрузке но при условии что input уже чем то заполнен, чтобы не пугать пользователя ошибками сразу

Вы сами себе противоречите. Как инпуты могут быть заполнены сразу при загрузке страницы (если вы не сохраняете стейт между перезагрузками)?

А вообще - смотрите в сторону хуков: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

---

### А в общем

**Настоятельно** рекомендую использовать одно из готовых решений для валидации форм, коих тысячи: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=vue%20validation , https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=vue%20mask и так далее.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html#Base-Example
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html#Another-Example-of-Custom-Validation

У Vue реально отличная документация и коммьюнити. Не изобретайте велосипедов :)